# What does "there" refer to in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I've read a sentence in a Burmese story.

> "The medico went to the nearest village and there in the bazaar he found various kinds of meat and fish"

I wanted to know whether "there" refers to "the nearest village" or "in the bazaar"

Comment: "There" is used, in this case, to tie together "nearest village" and "bazaar", so that one understands that the bazaar was in the village.  For this reason you can consider that it refers to the village, though technically it is ambiguous.

Answer (score -1):

In this context, it's both. If you need to pick one, pick **the bazaar** since the phrase *in the bazaar* defines *there* in that sentence, or at least constrains its location. That is, he found various kinds of meat and fish in the bazaar, which was located in the nearest village.

Assuming that villages are the larger unit, and that villages are not contained in bazaars, consider what happens when we switch the two locations:

- The medico went to the nearest *bazaar* and there in the *village* he found various kinds of meat and fish.

In this case, *there* would refer to the village, which happens to contain the bazaar. Interestingly, there is now no requirement that the meat and fish were found in the bazaar at all - the sentence allows the interpretation that they were found anywhere in the village.

Comment: Ok. according to your thoughtful comments ; i will know that ''there '' refers to in the nearest village . Is my choice right ?

Comment: @naykhit Which part of my answer are you referring to?

Comment: 'in the ...' is an apposition of 'there'.